# Passing IEnumerable Variables into .NET from ColdFusion

Tags: .net, coldfusion, ienumerable, coldfusion-10

I'm working on doing some ColdFusion 10 integration with a custom .NET DLL that I don't have the ability to tweak. During this process, I've been able to do everything that I need to do other than create an `IEnumerable` data type to pass to one of the methods of the object. Here's what I need to integration with:

[image]

It's the `Set_Events` method that I'm having the trouble with. I can create the individual Events that are supposed to be part of that enum variable, but I'm unable to create what it apparently is expecting as the proper variable type. I've tried doing this:

```
<cfset enum = createObject(".net", "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable__1") />
```

And this gives me a valid .NET object, with a `GetEnumerator()` method:

[image]

When I attempt to call that method:

```
<cfdump var="#enum.GetEnumerator()#">
```

That just gives me the following error:

```
The GetEnumerator method was not found.
```

## Other things I've tried:

### Creating a Generic List and Adding things:

```
<cfset eventList = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List`1", "dotNetCoreProxy.jar") />
<cfset eventList.Add(javacast("bigdecimal", "30.1234" )) />
```

That gives me the following error:

```
An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. If the class has a constructor that accepts an argument, you must call the constructor explicitly using the init(args) method. Error : System.Collections.Generic.List__1
```

And this gives me the same error again:

```
<cfset eventList = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List`1", "dotNetCoreProxy.jar") />
<cfset eventList.Add("foo") />
```

### Trying to Init the List

This code from Leigh works:

```
<cfset eventList = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List`1", "dotNetCoreProxy.jar") />
<cfset elemClass = createObject(".net", "System.String", "dotNetCoreProxy.jar") />
<cfset elemType = elemClass.getDotNetClass() />
<cfset eventList.init( elemType ) />
<cfset eventList.Add("foo") />
<cfdump var="#eventList#">
```

But this doesn't:

```
<cfobject type="dotnet" name="VideoWallEvent" class="Utilities.VideoWall.VideoWallEvent" assembly="#ExpandPath("Utilities.dll")#">
<cfset eventList = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List`1", "dotNetCoreProxy.jar") />
<cfset elemType = VideoWallEvent.getDotNetClass() />
<cfset eventList.init( elemType ) />
<cfdump var="#eventList#">
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to find a constructor for class System.Collections.Generic.List__1 that accepts parameters of type ( System.RuntimeType ).
```

### JNBProxyGUI.exe

This has been completely useless. I can browse to my Utilities.dll file, and add the System.Collections assembly from GAC, but the Build option in the Project menu is always disabled, and nothing shows in any of the panes once those assemblies have been added.

## Testing Methods

I've run all of the following code on one page:

```
<cfset UtilitiesProxy = ExpandPath("UtilitiesProxy.jar") />
<cfset DotNetCoreProxy = "dotNetCoreProxy.jar" />
<cfset CoStarUtilities = ExpandPath("CoStar.Utilities.dll") />

<h2>Try using base DLLs and DotNetCore</h2>
<cftry>
    <cfobject type="dotnet" name="VideoWallEvent" class="CoStar.Utilities.VideoWall.VideoWallEvent" assembly="#CoStarUtilities#">
    <cfset eventList = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List`1", DotNetCoreProxy) />
    <cfdump var="#eventList.init(VideoWallEvent.getDotNetClass())#"> (error line)
    <cfcatch>
        <h3><cfoutput>#cfcatch.type#</cfoutput></h3>
        <p><cfoutput>#cfcatch.message#: #cfcatch.detail#</cfoutput></p>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<h2>Try using the Utilities Proxy for Everything</h2>
<cftry>
    <cfobject type="dotnet" name="VideoWallEvent" class="CoStar.Utilities.VideoWall.VideoWallEvent" assembly="#UtilitiesProxy#">
    <cfset eventList = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List`1", UtilitiesProxy) /> (error line)
    <cfdump var="#eventList.init(VideoWallEvent.getDotNetClass())#">
    <cfcatch>
        <h3><cfoutput>#cfcatch.type#</cfoutput></h3>
        <p><cfoutput>#cfcatch.message#: #cfcatch.detail#</cfoutput></p>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<h2>Try using Utilities Proxy for VideoWall, and DotNetCore for List</h2>
<cftry>
    <cfobject type="dotnet" name="VideoWallEvent" class="CoStar.Utilities.VideoWall.VideoWallEvent" assembly="#UtilitiesProxy#">
    <cfset eventList = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List`1", DotNetCoreProxy) />
    <cfdump var="#eventList.init(VideoWallEvent.getDotNetClass())#"> (error line)
    <cfcatch>
        <h3><cfoutput>#cfcatch.type#</cfoutput></h3>
        <p><cfoutput>#cfcatch.message#: #cfcatch.detail#</cfoutput></p>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<h2>Try Initing Wall Event</h2>
<cftry>
    <cfobject type="dotnet" name="VideoWallEvent" class="CoStar.Utilities.VideoWall.VideoWallEvent" assembly="#CoStarUtilities#">
    <cfset VideoWallEvent.Init() />
    <cfset eventList = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List`1", DotNetCoreProxy) />
    <cfdump var="#eventList.init(VideoWallEvent.getDotNetClass())#"> (error line)
    <cfcatch>
        <h3><cfoutput>#cfcatch.type#</cfoutput></h3>
        <p><cfoutput>#cfcatch.message#: #cfcatch.detail#</cfoutput></p>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<h2>Try Initing Wall Event</h2>
<cftry>
    <cfobject type="dotnet" name="VideoWallEvent" class="CoStar.Utilities.VideoWall.VideoWallEvent" assembly="#CoStarUtilities#">
    <cfset VideoWallEvent.Init() />
    <cfset eventList = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List`1", DotNetCoreProxy) />
    <cfdump var="#eventList.init(VideoWallEvent)#"> (error line)
    <cfcatch>
        <h3><cfoutput>#cfcatch.type#</cfoutput></h3>
        <p><cfoutput>#cfcatch.message#: #cfcatch.detail#</cfoutput></p>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

And I get the following error output (hint, every single one of these fails).

```
09:22:45.045 - Object Exception - in C:/inetpub/LandsofAmerica/scribble/VideoWall/index.cfm : line 9
    Unable to find a constructor for class System.Collections.Generic.List__1 that accepts parameters of type ( System.RuntimeType ).

09:22:48.048 - coldfusion.runtime.dotnet.ProxyGenerationException - in C:/inetpub/LandsofAmerica/scribble/VideoWall/index.cfm : line 19
09:22:48.048 - Object Exception - in C:/inetpub/LandsofAmerica/scribble/VideoWall/index.cfm : line 31
    Unable to find a constructor for class System.Collections.Generic.List__1 that accepts parameters of type ( System.RuntimeType ).

09:22:48.048 - Object Exception - in C:/inetpub/LandsofAmerica/scribble/VideoWall/index.cfm : line 43
    Unable to find a constructor for class System.Collections.Generic.List__1 that accepts parameters of type ( System.RuntimeType ).

09:22:48.048 - Object Exception - in C:/inetpub/LandsofAmerica/scribble/VideoWall/index.cfm : line 55
    Unable to find a constructor for class System.Collections.Generic.List__1 that accepts parameters of type ( CoStar.Utilities.VideoWall.VideoWallEvent ).
```

I've generated a proxy with (what I think is) all of the items that I need.

[image: JNBProxyGUI]

## Conclusion

So now I'm stuck. I can instantiate and fill all of the necessary objects to make this thing work, I just can't push all of the objects together to make them work. What am I missing when trying to create the ENum object necessary to fill the Set_Events method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to use a concrete class (not the interface). However, looking at the method signature, it must be one that implements [System.Collections.**Generic**.IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and not [System.Collections.IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The latter is only for non-generic collections. One example of a generic collection you could use is [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), where `<T>` is the type of object the list holds. (You will need to review your API to determine the object type).

Unfortunately ... there is an [issue with Generic classes](http://www.rupeshk.org/blog/index.php/2009/08/how-to-use-net-generic-classes-from-coldfusion/). Essentially the tool used by `createObject` cannot generate proxies for Generics. (The blog entry says it was resolved in CF9, but in my tests I encountered the same problem with 9.0.1 - YMMV.) So you need to do it yourself using the [JNBProxyGUI.exe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13e1a-7ffd.html#WSf01dbd23413dda0e34d85971200ff1e6f4-7fff). Frankly it is not the most intuitive tool .. but after a little wrangling I managed to get it working under CF9. Fortunately it is only a one time event.

After exporting the generated proxies to a jar file, use the example in the blog entry to create a generic `List`. Just add the proxy jar to the assembly list.  Say the Collection stores simple [Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
    // create a generic list of strings ie new List<String>()
    path = "c:/path/yourGenericsProxy.jar,c:/path/yourApplication.dll"; 
    list = createObject(".net", "System.Collections.Generic.List__1", path);
    elemClass = createObject(".net", "System.String", path);
    elemType = elemClass.getDotNetClass();
    list.init( elemType );
```

Once the `List` is initialized, you can add a few elements to it:

```
    list.add( "foo" );
    list.add( "bar" );
```

<s>Then finally invoke GetEnumerator() and pass it into your method</s> Then pass the `List` into your method:

```
    // wrong: yourObject.Set_Events( list );
    yourObject.Set_Events( list );
```

(If you have any questions about generating the proxies, just ask.)

---

**UPDATE:**

As Dan pointed out, his method is using `IEnumerable` *not* IEnumerator. So the `List` itself should be passed into `set_Event`, not `Get_Enumerator()` (as in the previous example). Also, when you invoke `createObject`, **the assemblyList MUST include both the proxy jar AND the dll file**. Otherwise the method call(s) may fail. Turns out that was the cause of the later problems.

Below is a corrected version that works with CF10.

**Regenerated the proxy jar**

1. Open JNBProxyGUI.exe and select `Create new Java -> .NET Project`
2. Enter local java settings (My settings)

   - Remote host/port:  local host 6089
   - Java path:  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\jetty\jre\bin\java.exe
   - jnbcore.jar:  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\lib\jnbcore.jar
   - bcel.jar:  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\lib\becel-5.1-jnbridge.jar
3. Click `Project > Edit Assembly List > Add`. Locate and select "mscorlib.dll"
4. Click `Project > Add Classes from Assembly File`. Locate and select "mscorlib.dll" 
   (The gui then generates a list of classes. It might take a while).
5. In the "Environment" list, select `System.Collections.Generic` package and click `Add`.
6. Select `Edit > Check All in Exposed Proxies`
7. Select `Project > Build` and select the path and file name for the new proxy jar

**Cleanup:**

Just to be safe, I stopped CF and removed all generated proxy jars from `WEB-INF\cfclasses\dotNetProxy` **except** dotNetCoreProxy.jar. Then restarted CF and ran the code. It worked perfectly. String. (See complete code below).

---

**MyClass.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class MyClass {
        private IEnumerable<CustomClass> events;

        public void set_Events(IEnumerable<CustomClass> evts) 
        {
            this.events = evts;
        }

        public IEnumerable<CustomClass> get_Events()
        {
            return this.events;
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomClass.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class CustomClass
    {
        private string title;
        public CustomClass(string title)
        {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public string getTitle()
        {
            return this.title;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return getTitle();
        }
    }
}
```

**CF Code:**

```
<cfscript>
    // MUST include both proxy jar and DLL file
    path = arrayToList([ExpandPath("./MyLibrary.dll"), ExpandPath("genericListAndEnumerator.jar")]);
    //initialize custom class
    customObj = createObject(".net", "MyLibrary.CustomClass", path).init("Blah, blah");
    elemType = customObj.getDotNetClass();

    // create generic list of custom class
    list = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List__1", path);
    list.init( elemType );
    list.add( customObj );

    // test setter
    mainObj = createObject(".net", "MyLibrary.MyClass", path);
    mainObj.set_Events( list );

    // test getter
    enum = mainObj.get_Events().getEnumerator();
    writeDump(enum);
    while (enum.MoveNext()) {
        WriteDump("Current="& enum.Get_Current().toString());
    }
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to call a method of an interface. Instead, you need to create an instance of a class that implements that interface in order to pass that to `Set_Events()`. Here is a list of .NET classes which implement IEnumerable: [IEnumerable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Actually looking more closely at the screen shots, it needs to implement the *generic* IEnumerable interface. `System.Collections.IEnumerable` is for non-generic collections.

Comment: Good eye! I definitely missed that.

Comment: Yeah, missed it the first time too. Shame though, since CF/jnbridge seems to have some issues with the "Generic" variety ..