# Method Not Found Calling .NET Method with List from ColdFusion

Tags: .net, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

For some background, this is related to [Passing IEnumerable Variables into .NET from ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742477/passing-ienumerable-variables-into-net-from-coldfusion). I've changed the code to use a list instead, and have made progress, but continue to hit roadblocks when using anything other than simple data types with .NET and ColdFusion. So here's the current issue.

First, I have a .dll with the following VideoWallEvent.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CoStar.Utilities.VideoWall
{
    public class VideoWallEventActivityCollection
    {
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }
        public List<VideoWallEvent> Events { get; set; }

    }

    public class VideoWallEvent
    {

        public string ID { get; set; }
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }

        public VideoWallEvent(string EventID, decimal EventLatitude, decimal EventLongitude)
        {
            ID = EventID;
            Latitude = EventLatitude;
            Longitude = EventLongitude;
        }
    }
}
```

I've also generated a proxy object object using `JNBProxyGUI.exe` following instructions from the prior question. Give that the above dll, and the proxy jar I've generated, I run the following ColdFusion code:

```
<cfset UtilitiesProxy = ExpandPath("UtilitiesProxy.jar") />
<cfset CoStarUtilities = ExpandPath("CoStar.Utilities.dll") />
<cfset Paths = ArrayToList([CoStarUtilities, UtilitiesProxy])>

<cfset theEvent = CreateObject(".net", "CoStar.Utilities.VideoWall.VideoWallEvent", Paths) />
<cfset eventList = CreateObject(".net","System.Collections.Generic.List`1", Paths).init(theEvent.getDotNetClass()) />

<cfset eventList.Add(theEvent.Init("1234", javacast("bigdecimal","30.2669444"), javacast("bigdecimal","-97.7427778"))) />
<cfset eventList.Add(theEvent.Init("1235", javacast("bigdecimal","30.2669444"), javacast("bigdecimal","-97.7427778"))) />

<cfset eventCollection = CreateObject(".net", "CoStar.Utilities.VideoWall.VideoWallEventActivityCollection", CoStarUtilities) />
<cfdump var="#eventList.ToArray()#" label="Items in eventList" />
<hr />
<cfdump var="#eventCollection#" label="eventCollection" />
<cfdump var="#eventList#" label="eventList" />

<cfset eventCollection.Set_Events(eventList) />
```

This gives me the following output:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, I can successfully add items to the list, I can get the ActivityCollection object that expects a List object, but calling the `Set_Events` method and passing the List throws the following error:

```
The Set_Events method was not found.

Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types 
or the Set_Events method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot
decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments. 
If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast 
function to reduce ambiguity.

The error occurred in C:/inetpub/scribble/VideoWall/index.cfm: line 17
15 :    <cfdump var="#eventList#" label="eventList" />
16 : 
17 :    <cfset eventCollection.Set_Events(eventList) />
```

So I now need help figuring out how to properly push this List into the Set_Events() method.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what you get if you call <cfdump var="#eventCollection.Get_Events()#" />

Comment: I am wondering if the DotNetProxy is incorrectly setting up the Set_Events() mutator. I wonder if it would make any difference if you initialized the Events property with an empty List<VideoWallEvent> during construction.

Comment: If I were the swearing type, I would swear... a lawt. I was using just the Utilities.dll in the path argument. Once I included both the Utilities.dll *and* the proxy I created from the JNBProxyGUI.exe, everything appears to be filling properly.

Comment: Believe it or not it is just an assembly path problem. You have to use both jars in the assembly list, not just `CoStarUtilities`. (Edit: - Nevermind I see you caught that).

Comment: Leigh, please post your comment as the answer and I'll mark it as accepted, since you caught the issue, and I just happened to get it right while cleaning up my variable references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(From the comments)*

Believe it or not it is just an assembly path problem. You have to use both files in the assembly list, not just `CoStarUtilities`, ie:

```
 <cfset eventCollection = CreateObject(".net"
                 , "CoStar.Utilities.VideoWall.VideoWallEventActivityCollection"
                 , Paths ) />
```