# How to set .NET enum in ColdFusion

Tags: .net, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Having called a .Net object as shown below (cfdump shown beneath)...

```
<cfobject type=".NET" name="GoCardless" class="GoCardlessSdk.GoCardless" assembly="#expandpath("../GoCardlessSdk.dll")#,#expandpath("../Newtonsoft.Json.dll")#,#expandpath("../RestSharp.dll")#">
```

[image: cfdump of .Net object]

I now need to set an enum. The example .Net code for this would be:

```
GoCardless.Environment = GoCardless.Environments.Sandbox;
```

The C# code for the class is shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using GoCardlessSdk.Api;
using GoCardlessSdk.Connect;
using GoCardlessSdk.Helpers;
using GoCardlessSdk.Partners;

namespace GoCardlessSdk
{
    public static class GoCardless
    {
        static GoCardless()
        {
            AccountDetails = new AccountDetails();
        }

        public enum Environments
        {
            Production,
            Sandbox,
            Test
        }

        public static readonly Dictionary<Environments, string> BaseUrls =
            new Dictionary<Environments, string>
                {
                    {Environments.Production, "https://gocardless.com"},
                    {Environments.Sandbox, "https://sandbox.gocardless.com"},
                    {Environments.Test, "http://gocardless.com"}
                };

        private static string _baseUrl;

        public static string BaseUrl
        {
            get { return _baseUrl ?? BaseUrls[Environment ?? Environments.Production]; }
            set { _baseUrl = value.Trim(); }
        }

        public static Environments? Environment { get; set; }

        public static AccountDetails AccountDetails { get; set; }

        public static ApiClient Api
        {
        get { return new ApiClient(AccountDetails.Token); }
        }

        public static ConnectClient Connect
        {
            get { return new ConnectClient(); }
        }

        public static PartnerClient Partner
        {
            get { return new PartnerClient(); }
        }


        internal static string UserAgent = GetUserAgent();
        private static string GetUserAgent()
        {
            try
            {
                return "gocardless-dotnet/v" + GetAssemblyFileVersion();
            }
            catch
            {
                return "gocardless-dotnet";
            }
        }
        private static string GetAssemblyFileVersion()
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (GoCardless));
            var attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false)
                    as AssemblyFileVersionAttribute[];

            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length == 1)
            {
                return attributes[0].Version;
            }
            return "";
        }

        private static Func<string> _generateNonce;
        internal static Func<string> GenerateNonce
        {
            get { return _generateNonce ?? (_generateNonce = Utils.GenerateNonce); }
            set { _generateNonce = value; }
        }

        private static Func<DateTimeOffset> _getUtcNow; 
        internal static Func<DateTimeOffset> GetUtcNow
        {
            get { return _getUtcNow ?? (_getUtcNow = () => DateTimeOffset.UtcNow); }
            set { _getUtcNow = value; }
        } 
    }
    }
```

Is anybody able to explain to me how I would set the enum in ColdFusion?

Thanks!

**Update**

In response to Leigh's utility class solution my code is as follows:

```
<cfscript>

    GoCardless = createObject(".net", "GoCardlessSdk.GoCardless","path to GoCardless DLL,paths to supporting DLLs");

    Environments = createObject(".net", "GoCardlessSdk.GoCardless$Environments", "path to GoCardless DLL");

    util = createObject(".net", "GoCardlessSdk.GoCardlessSdkUtil", "path to utility DLL");

    dumps etc...

</cfscript>
```

If I remove the last createobject() call the first two run perfectly well. Even if I include the paths to *all* DLLs in *all* createobject() calls I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

*(Disclaimer: My current test environment is CF9, but the results were the same as yours)*

Normally you can modify a field by using [`set_FieldName( value )`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-789e.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13e1a-7fef). However, I can see from your screen shot that method does not exist. I was not sure why, so I did a little searching. Based on what I have read, your class is using [`Nullable Types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

```
    public static Environments? Environment { get; set; }
```

That seems to be the root of the problem. From what I can tell, jnbridge ([underlying tool used for .net interop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13e1a-7ffd.html)) does not seem to generate proxies when Nullable Types are involved. That would explain why the methods to access the `Evironment` field are missing.  If you remove the `?` operator, it works just fine.

**CF Code:**

```
<cfscript>
    goCardless = createObject(".net", "GoCardlessSdk.GoCardless", ExpandPath("./GoCardlessSdk.dll"));
    Environments = createObject(".net", "GoCardlessSdk.GoCardless$Environments", ExpandPath("./GoCardlessSdk.dll"));
    goCardLess.set_Environment(Environments.Test);
    writeDump( goCardLess.get_Environment().toString() );
</cfscript>
```

**Test Class:** (Without Nullable Type)

```
namespace GoCardlessSdk
{
    public static class GoCardless
    {
        static GoCardless()
        {
        }

        public enum Environments
        {
            Production,
            Sandbox,
            Test
        }

        public static Environments Environment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**

- So modifying the class to eliminate the Nullable type is one option
- Another possibility is to [generate the proxies manually](http://www.rupeshk.org/blog/index.php/2009/08/how-to-use-net-generic-classes-from-coldfusion/). jnbridge also [has issues with .net generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747393/104223), so generating the proxies yourself *might* work.
- A third possibility is to write a helper class that sets/gets the value without using the Nullable type. It is a bit of a hack, but does work.

**Update 2/3:**

Here is a rough example of a simpler helper class. If you want the helper `get` method to return null (like the original) then use `getNullableEnvironment`. If you prefer to return a default, instead of null, use `getEnvironment`. As far as setup all I did was:

- Created a new solution in VS
- Added reference to GoCardlessSDK.dll

---

```
<cfscript>
   dllPaths = arrayToList( [ ExpandPath("GoCardlessUtil.dll")
                            , ExpandPath("GoCardlessSdk.dll")
                            , ExpandPath("Newtonsoft.Json.dll")
                            , ExpandPath("RestSharp.dll")
                            ]
                        );
    goCardless = createObject(".net", "GoCardlessSdk.GoCardless", dllPaths);
    Environments = createObject(".net", "GoCardlessSdk.GoCardless$Environments", dllPaths);
    util = createObject(".net", "GoCardlessUtil.GoCardlessSdkUtil", dllPaths );
    WriteDump("before="& util.getNullableEnvironment());
    util.setEnvironment(Environments.Production);
    WriteDump("after="& util.getNullableEnvironment().toString());
</cfscript>
```

**GoCardlessSdkUtil.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using GoCardlessSdk;

namespace GoCardlessUtil
{
    public class GoCardlessSdkUtil
    {
        public static void setEnvironment(GoCardless.Environments environ)
        {
            GoCardless.Environment = environ;
        }

        /*
        // Enum's cannot be null. So we are applying a default
        // value ie "Test" instead of returning null
        public static GoCardless.Environments getEnvironment()
        {
            return GoCardless.Environment.HasValue ? GoCardless.Environment.Value : GoCardless.Environments.Test;
        }
        */

        // This is the closest to the original method
        // Since enum's cannot be null, we must return type Object instead of Environment
        // Note: This will return be null/undefined the first time it is invoked
        public static Object getNullableEnvironment()
        {
            return GoCardless.Environment;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how I would go about the third option? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this Leigh. Unfortunately I am getting the error 'Class GoCardlessSdk.GoCardlessSdkUtil not found in the specified assembly list' when I run the above code.

Comment: It worked with the sample classes above. Though I have not tested it with separate dlls ie gocardless.dll + utility.dll) Silly question, did you append the utility dll to your assembly list? In other words, you must include *both* dlls in the assembly list for **all** of your `createobject` calls.

Comment: @MichaelHenson - I was able to to create a separate project, add a reference to the gocardless.dll, and it seemed to work okay for me. (Note: I did change the helper project name). Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Same error still I'm afraid. Maybe it is not compiling correctly. How are you compiling the C# code? I am using the following call from the command line 'csc /t:library GoCardlessSdkUtil.cs -> GoCardlessSdkUtil.dll'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33785/discussion-between-leigh-and-michael-henson)